# Incremental make fails when source file deleted

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple C program with two source files, and the Makefile generates dependencies automatically, as documented in [section 4.14 of the GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites):

```
all: main

%.d: %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@; \
         $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
         sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
         rm -f $@.$$$$

include main.d
include hello.d

main: main.o hello.o
```

This creates files like `main.d` that look like so:

```
main.o main.d : main.c hello.h
```

The problem comes if I make a change to the source code (and Makefile) to remove hello.c and hello.h. Upon the next incremental rebuild, `make` fails:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `hello.h', needed by `main.d'.  Stop.
```

The `main.d` file is out of date, but `make` cannot rebuild it since (according to the stale `main.d`) it still depends on the no-longer-existent `hello.h`.

In this situation, a clean build will succeed. How can I get the incremental build to succeed as well?

Comment: Auto-deps are intended for (very) large projects. If you have only two sources plus a single header, you definitely should describe them manually.

Comment: Make manual is outdated. Read this [article](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation). In fact, the script could be made shorter, but gcc sometimes outputs .d file younger than .o So the solution looks a bit bloated to deal with this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `%.d` recipe so that the dependencies are only considered if the file still exists. The new Makefile rule:

```
%.d: %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@; \
         $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
         sed --in-place 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' $@.$$$$ ; \
         sed 's^: \(.*\)^: $$(foreach t,\1,$$(if $$(wildcard $$t),$$t,))^g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
         rm -f $@.$$$$
```

The second `sed` modifies the `main.d` to look like:

```
main.o main.d : $(foreach t,main.c hello.h,$(if $(wildcard $t),$t,))
```

Thus if any of the dependent files should disappear, `make` will not complain.

One drawback to this approach is that an incremental build may succeed in situations where a clean build would fail. For example, if `hello.h` was deleted without properly removing the `#include` from `main.c`, then the incremental build would succeed (since it won't try to rebuild `main.o`) while a full build would fail.

Are there any other drawbacks to this approach? For instance, are there any cases where an incremental build would be incomplete?

Comment: Even better would be to use the -MP option to GCC, to create an empty target for each dependency, as explained in @Matt's link